# Youtbe serves js which causes warnings in console: Use the "aria-label" attribute instead

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Youtube serves js file which causes chrome warnings in console.
[image]

File address: https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/html5player-ru_RU-vflgXY8IB/html5player.js

How can I fix that?

Comment: same here , started today (as far as I can see)

Comment: Just tested on a clean html page (there's nothing on that page but the necessary body , html, head - tags ... and a simple clean "<iframe>" embed code, straight out of Youtube, and I get all these warnings.
I guess a Google dev is just playing around with some stuff, will possibly fix itself.

Comment: ruined console with all those messages...players ))

Comment: also getting this error, just today. only a few hours ago in fact.

Comment: There's really nothing to fix, as these are just warnings; you can turn them off in the console by setting it to not display warnings. It shouldn't impact anything from executing.

Comment: @jlmcdonald, true. But it helps only if you don't use warnings youself...

Answer (score 2):

Please Note: that it's cause you need to put these attribute that it's complaining about. To disable warnings you can add aria-label="..." to the specific following items more so in the following elements.

- input
- md-button
- md-dialog
- md-icon
- md-checkbox
- md-radio-button
- md-slider
- md-switch

Add the attributes that are required to enhance your Performance.

```html
 <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="..." ng-click="vm.addItem()">
       <md-icon md-font-icon="zmdi zmdi-edit"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```